# Using rake with a non-ruby project

Tags: ruby, rake, autoconf

A workmate floated the idea of using rake as a build system for a non-ruby project. Is it possible to extend rake to compliment other languages where the autoconf toolset would usually be used?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but note there are other viable buildsystems than autoconf too. CMake and QMake are both great, and quite popular.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are examples of this, like [buildr](http://incubator.apache.org/buildr/), the drop in-replacement for maven (for java) that is built on top of rake. There's also [raven](http://raven.rubyforge.org/) for java.

Answer (score 2):

Tools like [waf](http://code.google.com/p/waf/) and [SCons](http://www.scons.org/) are Python-based build systems that are developed specifically for broad language support.

Answer (score 1):

You can find how to use Rake as an easy replacement for Makefile in the manual...

I use it almost exlusevely for build that I write myself... If you use Java better choice would be Ant and Maven - they have a lot of code behind them... But, as for me, you have to be a little brainf*ed to program in XML, so I often use Rake for many task, and invoke it from Ant/Maven, like that:

```
<target name="custom_task">
    <exec executable="/usr/bin/env">
        <arg value="rake"/>
        <arg value="some-task"/>
        <arg value="param" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

It may not be super efficient, especially if you have to run anything on the JVM it can't use Ant's, so it is not the best idea... I haven't tried JRuby, maybe it would be worth trying...
But for other task - filehandling, doing something with text files, etc. it works really nice for me :-)

Answer (score 0):

I use it to deploy (Capistrano) on several non-Rails projects.  One Java (servlet) and several static HTML sites.

Very handy.

Answer (score 0):

I use it to compile Flex applications. I've written [wrappers around the Flex SDK command line tools](http://github.com/iconara/flexutils) -- it's easy to do for any tool chain that can be called from the command line.